# How to work with the .autostart directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to launch a java application when the system starts , so I created the `.autostart` directory in the `~/` directory. Now what should I do to make the java application starts with the system ?

Comment: You mean you lied in your other question when you "saw" something?

Comment: I just saw the tip that to launch an app with the system then the .autostart directory should be used. But he didn't say how to do !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an executable bash script. For example: `java Yourcompiledcode` in `mystartupscript.sh` and make the sh file executable by running `chmod +x mystartupscript.sh`. Just make sure that the script is in the correct directory.

EDIT 1: In `KDE` you have the `~/.kde/Autostart` folder where you put in your scripts, which run after kde startup. In Ubuntu, you are probably using `Gnome3`, so you'd have to create a folder `~/.config/autostart` and put the script in there

Comment: how to create a bash script ?

Comment: open an editor. Enter your script. Save it with a `.sh` extension. Use `chmod +x yourscript.sh` from the terminal.

Comment: if the java class file is not in the `~/` directory which contains the `.autostart` directory how to write correctly the calling of the java class file in the script ?

Comment: `java <path-to-your-file>/youjavafile`

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you just have to put an executable into that folder. But why don't you use the autostart manager? `System > Settings > Autostart`

Btw. I think this belongs to [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)